# How to add H264 streaming module to Apache?

Tags: apache, module, streaming, h.264, wampserver

I want to add the H264 streaming module to Apache. I'm on Windows using the stack WAMPserver 2.2 with Apache 2.2.22, and I have put the module (mod_h264_streaming.so) in the module directory. I've added the LoadModule code into httpd.conf but, alas, the server doesn't work (the icon shows orange). This is what I entered in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule h264_streaming_module modules/mod_h264_streaming.so
```

I have no idea what or where the problem is, and it's causing many headaches. This particular module is essential to my project. I realize this is probably vague troubleshooting, but I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is in your Apache error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by Step

1- At first Download Visual Studio 2008 x64 SP1, be sure to install the Visual C++ 2008 x64 SP1 Redistributable Package
it can be downloaded from;

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=BA9257CA-337F-4B40-8C14-157CFDFFEE4E  (Setup this)

2- Download Apache module mod_h264_streaming from ; https://www.apachehaus.net/modules/mod_h264_streaming/ in the below.Before download Please careful about your apache version.consider it.

3- Extrach files , copy "mod_h264_streaming.so"

3- If you are using Wamp server go the C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\modules and drop(add,copy what ever you say) mod_h264_streaming file to the path. If you are not using wamp go to C:/Apache24/modules/ and add mod_h264_streaming.

4- Then Go to httpd.conf (in the C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf path) , open with notepad++ find load modules line
just like ;

```
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so    // opened module
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so // closed module
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
```

When you find the lines add this ;

```
 LoadModule h264_streaming_module modules/mod_h264_streaming.so
```

save and quit. Finally restart the apache server. Module is ready to serve you.

Comment: Thanks! Can't remember what I did wrong back then, but it works great now.